# Правильно ли будет сказать "темные круги и мешки под глазами"?

Tags: лексика, порядок-слов

Верно ли, что "темные круги и мешки под глазами" это все равно, что "темные круги и темные мешки под глазами"?

Правильнее ли будет сказать "мешки и темные круги под глазами"?

Полное предложение: "Как скрыть темные круги и мешки под глазами?"

Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Само предложение - правильное, и лучше его не растолковывать, чтобы не запутаться. Круги темные, а мешки сами по себе - могут быть при кругах (тогда они цвета кругов на том же месте) или без кругов (и без цвета), которые, в свою очередь, могут быть и без мешков, т. е. плоскими.